# Difficulties to make package and import (importedNamespace) working when I have several files in XText

Tags: eclipse, xtext

I am trying to implement the package/import mechanism into my DSL.
It works perfectly when I have a single file but not with different files.

Even the [15 Minutes Tutorial](https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/102_domainmodelwalkthrough.html) doesn't work for me. I don't manage to make it work even by coping/pasting the code from the website. I only modify the grammar file.

I tried to investigate this problem further, but found nothing relevant on the Internet.

I noticed that the resource set contains only the current files edited, not the other files present in the project. To see that, I add this line of code in the validator and the scope provider: `println(context.eResource.resourceSet.resources)`.
From my understanding of how XText works, I expected to get one resource for each file present inside the project.

When I create the project, I usually create a "General Project". But I got the same issue with a Java one.

Here my configuration:

- macOS Mojave, v. 10.14.1
- Eclipse DSL Tools v. 2018-09 (4.9.0)
- Xtext v.2.16.0v20181203-0514
- JDK 1.8

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Have you tried adding the Xtext nature to your project, I remember it might have an effect on the indexing of models of a project for this mechanism.

Comment: so simply reference to super entity or relation does not work? then you definitely make sure  project has Xtext nature and build (rightclick on project -> configure) and you have build automaticaly on

Comment: could you post your sample models?

Comment: @user1292456 after checking, the project has the XText nature

Comment: @ChristianDietrich The automatic build was set to off. After turning it on, it works perfectly!
Thank you very much for your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @ChristianDietrich in his comment, the project build was off. After turning it on, the import works perfectly.